# Javascript : Will a function call all callbacks for all functions that ever called it?

Tags: javascript, callback

Say we have a function.

```
function kevin(cb){
   //Ok  then, so async stuff here, then, when done, 
   cb(1); <== reply;
}
```

Then :

```
....
kevin(x=> console.log(x));
```

Then another block calls `kevin()` before the above call receives a reply.

```
kevin(y=> console.log(y));
```

I'm a bit confused after working with Java for a while, with the above, in java, if these callbacks were Java Interfaces, and the second call to `kevin` happened before the first call was returned, the second call would override the first, and only the second would be returned, requiring the `composite pattern` to make sure that all callbacks are recorded and fulfilled when the method is done.

But in Javascript, I'm not getting any errors, everything works and all function callbacks that call `kevin()` are being called.

I'm doing this in Angular with typescript. So the above are actually methods in classes.

Comment: Don't know exactly what doubt you have. What do you mean by *call `kevin()` before the above call receives a reply*? What reply? When you do `kevin(y => console.log(y))` the function is executed immediately.

Comment: @OscarPaz Maybe OP meant that two calls are asynchronous?

Comment: Maybe. That's why I am asking. However, there's nothing asynchronous in the example

Comment: @OscarPaz you call a function, with a callback, wait for it, isn't that asynchronous?

Comment: In this case there's nothing *happening later* (sort of the definition of asynchronous). `x => setTimeout(() => console.log(x), 1000)` would be an asynchronous callback.

Comment: Looking at your reputations, you guys do get what I'm asking, you just wanna be funny with semantics.

Comment: Programming is all about details, we just want to ensure we're talking about the same thing so answers will be accurate and helpful to you.

Comment: Could you please share the equivalent java code having the described behavior ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subsequent function calls will *not* in any way replace previous function calls. If some asynchronous event is awaited inside a function, then a new callback is scheduled on the event loop for each await.  Simple example:

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log(1));
setTimeout(() => console.log(2));
setTimeout(() => console.log(3));
```

All three callbacks will fire with their respective values.

The only time you will get interference is if you have shared variables:

```js
let foo = 'bar';

setTimeout(() => console.log(foo));
setTimeout(() => foo = 'baz', 500);
setTimeout(() => console.log(foo), 1000);
```

The result of the last callback may or may not be what you expect, if you're unaware that the shared `foo` is being manipulated in another callback.

Comment: 1+, ok so, every call to a function `kevin` will create a new object where that `kevin` will exist? As opposed to one instance of `kevin` handling all calls?

Comment: No. `kevin` is a *function*, not an object. (Well, asterisk asterisk footnote definition of objects…) It will put a function call on the stack, just like any regular function call. If some asynchronous event is awaited inside the function, then a new callback is scheduled on the event loop for each await.

Comment: Ok .thanks, didn't know about `If some asynchronous event is awaited inside the function, then a new callback is scheduled on the  "event loop" for each await`, thought I had to do this loop and handle this manually, like in Java.

Comment: No, Javascript does not expose details of the underlying event loop to userland code. It's just there.

Comment: I'd love to see how this `event loop` is handled underneath, please include some links if you have some.